# DivideByZeroExeption in Csharp Programing

Tags: dividebyzeroexception

I am trying to handle **DivideByZeroExeption** in C# but the code do not catch the exeption, the Console print result of 10 / d is ∞

```
            double d = 0;
            try
            {
                double value = 10 / d;
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Ignore...");
            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty51D.png)
But when I changed type of **d** from **double** to **int** or **long**, this code above works normally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258124/divide-by-zero-and-no-error/44258269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int test = 0;
        try
        {
            double value = 10 / test;
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Ignore...");
        }
```

> Now this code will give you the error which you are expecting.
>   It is treating d as something else.
>   DivideByZeroException comes only in case of integer.