# How is dividing by 0 not a 'divide by zero' exception?

Tags: c#

This code produces a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because `numberOfIntervals` is infinity. But why doesn't this produce a `divide by zero` exception? The calculation ends up being -524 / 0. Shouldn't that produce a `divide by zero` exception?

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);
DateTime referenceDate = new DateTime(2020, 6, 8);

double numberOfIntervals = (startDate - referenceDate).TotalDays / 0;

Console.WriteLine(numberOfIntervals);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? (you divide a double by an int)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258124/divide-by-zero-and-no-error/44258269

Comment: The numerator is a double.  So it becomes the max positive number for a double.

Comment: It partially answers my question. That's helpful, but *why* not throw `divide by zero` for doubles as well?

Comment: Sometimes in floating-point arithmetic it's useful to be able to represent INFINITY... So `1f / 0 == double.PositiveInfinity` will be True

Comment: This is going to be negative infinity surely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation is done by [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard.

> Division by zero: an operation on finite operands gives an exact infinite result, e.g., 1/0 or log(0). By default, returns ±infinity.

Comment: I see that in the exception handling section:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Exception_handling
I guess I'm still wondering why treat double differently than int.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero